# Application Design, How to call methods on far away classes without creating a mess?

Tags: java, class, oop, uml, software-design

I have a graphic example so you understand what I mean:

MasterClass wants to use class A, B and C, but B is inside A, and C is inside B.
So the two ways that I know how to solve this problem are these:

1.Class B will have methods that will call directly into Class C methods, and class A will have methods that will call B methods (including C Methods) as the image:
[image: Example1]

2.On Solution two every class has a getter what will return the class that they are usign so the other classes can call their methods directly, I mean, if MasterClass wants to use methods on C, it will call method getClassB() from Class A and then call the method getClassC():
[image]

Sadly I end up always on situations like this, so I dont know if it is a very commun situation when designing or it is just that i dont know how to design. In the last case, I will be gratefull if you can recommend me material so I can learn How to create clean  and modular programs since a lot of my programms end up with a lot of classes interconecting.

Comment: The question is too broad; there is no right answer. Depending on context it could be answered in many ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first question you should ask yourself, is whether these classes are implementation details, or, if they are associated classes that `MasterClass` could legitimately interact with independently:

- If `B` and `C` are implementation details,  you should not leak them.  Option 1,  forwarding the call, is the option to chose.  This is justified by the [principle of least knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). If the implementation details change,  your forwarding method could hide these changes to `MasterClass`.
- If `B` and `C` are classes that are associated with `A` and at the same level of abstraction, and if moreover `MasterClass` could legitimately have to know about them, then Option 2, direct access, seems to be a reasonable alternative, because of the [interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle). If the interface of any of this class would evolve, the impact would be limited to the implementation of the classes that directly use it.

So there's no universal answer:  you need to analyse case by case the nature of the relationship between these classes.  What can help is to think about the acceptable consequences of changes in the interfaces.

Comment: I will start looking for books that teach object-oriented design, I am realizing that I don't really know much about it.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, I guess the short answer would be, if you mean B and C are actually defined inside of A and B (respectively), then don't define them there, but as classes that are "outside", at the same level as Master and A.  Then Master can call them directly.

Having classes that expose other classes through properties / getters is feasible, as you know, but isn't following the so-called Law of Demeter, and is a kind of "feature envy" as well, among other concerns.  After all, then your classes are not encapsulating their contents, but exposing them.

Generally, a class should know about another class only in order to do something with it internally.  So if Master needed something from C, which is defined through two levels of nesting, it would only be because some method on B rolls up C's capabilities with some of B's, and then some method on A rolls up something from B (and therefore C) with its own stuff...  that Master then calls.

As a rule I'd say it's most manageable to keep classes un-nested except in special circumstances.

Comment: After reading both anwers I am realizing that even that I know OOP, I still need knowledge about how to design it, thanks for mentioning these rules and good practices, probably my best option is to read a book and investigate about object-oriented design.